# How to install multiple nuget targetframeworks

Tags: .net, nuget

Current project "B" is in .net version 4.6.2. I am copying in the packages.config from another project "A" which would be sharing the code with the current project. The packages in the "A" has both net451 and net462 dependencies. How would I install the same in project B instead of forcing everything to 4.6.2 when I do an `update-package -reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use net451 libraries.

If Some libs are existed only for net462, then you should change version of .net for another project, and use net462 in both your projects.